# C - How to copy part of an array of string into another?

Tags: c

Is there a simple and elegant way to split an array from an index?

In my program I am getting a array of strings (argv), and I want to ignore the program name and some of its arguments, copying the rest in an array.

For example, the content of `argv` is `{"program_name", "-o", "file1", "file2"}`

I want to retrieve `"file1"` and `"file2"` in an array just to make an easy iteration over it.

```
 // PSEUDO
 char *files[argc - 2] = argv.split(2, argc - 2)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, `argv` is not usually a `vector`. Please make a [mre]

Comment: why don't you just loop over `argv` starting from the desired index

Comment: @cigien he probably just meant "array" and used the wrong word.
Anyway, there really isn't a better way other than iterating with a loop. You could also just make a loop from i=2 to i<argc, there is no need to copy.

Comment: In my code, if no files given, I will have to work with a default. Just to make something generalized.

Comment: C or C++? The answers for each are quite different, please only tag one of the languages

Comment: *Is there a simple and elegant way to split an array from an index?* - well, this is C, if you want something simple and elegant you'll have to code it simply and elegantly yourself :')

Comment: You could use a command line argument parser. https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pointer arithmetic to make it in an elegant way:

```
char** filenames = argv + 2;
```

Just be sure that you have at least 2 arguments before your filenames as you wish.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if(argc > 2){
      //char** that points to the first filename
      char** filenames = argv + 2;
      //number of filenames available to iterate
      int num_of_filenames = argc - 2;

      //Printing each name
      int i = 0;
      for(i = 0; i < num_of_filenames; i++){
        printf("%s\n",filenames[i]);
      }
    }
  return 0;
}
```